# Change alpha background grid colours

Tags: interface, customization

I suffer from photo sensitivity issues, is it possible to change the background grid colours when rendering to a transparent image? Preferably both shades to a mid, flat grey so as not to induce migraines.

My interim solution is to switch Color and Alpha to just Color on the Display Channels tab.

[image: Render on transparent background as seen in Blender]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the *Transparent Checkerboard* under Preferences > Themes > User Interface > Transparent Checkerboard:

[image: Check]